# How to run spring batch job multiple times with different job parameters?

Tags: java, configuration, jboss7.x, spring-batch

We have created a simple spring batch job with single step. There are custom implemented ItemReader and ItemWriter. The ItemReader gets the initial data from job parameter. The batch runs perfectly when run as a standalone java process. But what we want is to host the batch on some server. Therefore, we have created REST service to initialize the batch. The service calls the job URL and passes some parameter. This parameter is passed as job parameter to the batch. The service and job run fine when it is called for one parameter.

But when we call the service more than once (twice for testing purpose), the batch behaves strangely. We are passing different job parameters. But when the execution starts for second job initialization, the job parameter value which is received by the ItemReader is the same as the one for the first execution. And both execution interfere with each other, sharing database connection, interfering with data retrieved etc.

We have tried setting the restartable parameter to false but it didn't work. We have also tried the following solution:

[Can we create multiple instances of a same java(spring) batch job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092790/can-we-create-multiple-instances-of-a-same-javaspring-batch-job)

The above solution started giving "Interrupted attempting lock" error in JBoss.

On further investigation we found that ItemReader is getting initialized only once. That is why it is getting same job parameter value and is interfering with the previous execution.

EDIT
Following is the job configuration:

```
<bean id="jobLauncher"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
<property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
```

`<job id="jobid" restartable="false">
    <step id="step1">
      <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer"
            commit-interval="2">
        </chunk>
      </tasklet>
    </step>
  </job>`

Following is the code snippet to launch the job:

```
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job) context.getBean("jobid");

try {
    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("key","value").toJobParameters();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution? Am I missing some configuration for the step?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.  Can you provide how you are launching the job?  2.  Can you provide your job configuration?  3.  Have you looked at Spring Batch Admin?  It provides a REST service that does what you're trying to do...

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I have added the configuration and code for launching the jobs.

Comment: I know the issue is a bit old, but did you find out how to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if we create the Context and JobLauncher objects statically, that is, if there is only one instance of these two objects, the above thing can work. In this way, we can launch the same job multiple times, but with different parameters.

```
Class MyClass{
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
private static JobLauncher jobLauncher = null;

static{
    String[] springConfig = {BatchTokeniserConstants.SPRING_CONFIG_FILE_NAME};
        try {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
            jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
            BatchTokeniserUtils.loadSystemVaiables();
        } catch (BeansException e) {

        }
     }      
}
```

Now the jobLauncher can be used to launch any job any number of time.

I hope it helps others.